# Can I use blender as a photo and video viewer?

Tags: image, video, windows

I want to know If I can use blender as a photo and video viewer?
Like If I have a photo on my computer I just have to press "open with" blender and blender automatically open on the UV image editor if it is a photo or on the video editor if it is a video.
If not can this be done by a script or something?

Comment: a suggestion : associate these types with a shell script which launch blender with the appropriate python script  based on the file type

Comment: I dont know what is the shell script is,can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender can be a useful image viewer for some formats like multilayer OpenEXR. I just expanded a bit on Chebhou's answer by creating a python script that calls blender, I expect this can be used on any *nix platform included OSX and possibly even windows.

The script that gets called or set as the application to open image files is -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import call
from sys import argv
import os

sdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(argv[0]))

calllist = [
    'blender',
    '--factory-startup',
    os.path.join(sdir, 'blend_image_view.blend'),
    '--python',
    os.path.join(sdir, 'blend_open_image_file.py'),
    '--',
    ]

# add the args we get as filenames
calllist.extend(argv)

call(calllist)
```

The factory-startup and blend file can be removed from the list of options sent to blender. I have blender setup to start with a window that fills two monitors, that doesn't work as well when used as a simple image viewer. I also setup a start file that has two simple layouts for image and movie viewing, leaving a window clear of any excess.

The main working script I adjusted a bit to handle multiple files. When multiple movies are opened I have them in separate channels, with all but the first video muted. I really don't think blender is a good choice for video viewing, this could be improved by adding a way to extract frame rates and resolutions to setup blender to match, which doesn't work well if you open multiple videos with different frame rates and sizes.

```
import bpy
from sys import argv
import os

# change these two values to match screens names available
# UV Editing
blenderImageScreenName = 'ImageViewer'
# Video Editing
blenderMovieScreenName = 'MovieViewer'

acceptedImgFiles = ['.bmp', '.cin', '.dpx',  '.exr',
                    '.hdr', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.jp2',
                    '.j2k', '.png', '.rgb',  '.tga',
                    '.tif'
                    ]
acceptedMovFiles = ['.avi',  '.flv', '.h264', '.mov',
                    '.mpeg', '.mpg', '.mp2',  '.mp3',
                    '.mp4',  '.mkv', '.ogg',  '.xvid'
                    ]

fileStartIdx = argv.index('--') + 2
numFilesToOpen = len(argv) - fileStartIdx
showAreaType = 'image'
curChann = 1

for i in range(numFilesToOpen):
    filename = os.path.abspath(argv[fileStartIdx + i])
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()

    if ext in acceptedImgFiles:
        bpy.ops.image.open(filepath=argv[fileStartIdx + i])
    elif ext in acceptedMovFiles:
        # while we will open video files, blender isn't the best option here
        # When opening multiple videos, each video is imported into a new track
        # tracks after the first will be muted to prevent a terrifying
        # mess of multiple audio tracks
        # end frame is set to the longest video track imported
        # frame rate is left default and will need to be adjusted for each video
        nc = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie(name=argv[fileStartIdx + i],
                filepath=os.path.abspath(argv[fileStartIdx + i]), frame_start=1, channel=curChann)
        if bpy.context.scene.frame_end < nc.frame_duration:
            bpy.context.scene.frame_end = nc.frame_duration
        # I expected new_movie() to import video and sound
        # but that doesn't happen so we also add sound from the same file
        nca = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound(name=argv[fileStartIdx + i],
                filepath=os.path.abspath(argv[fileStartIdx + i]), frame_start=1, channel=curChann+1)
        if curChann > 1:
            nc.mute = True
            nca.mute = True
        curChann += 2
        showAreaType = 'video'
    else:
        print("Don't know what type of file this is -",filename)

if showAreaType == 'image':
    bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens[blenderImageScreenName]
    # make first image active
    for area in bpy.data.screens[blenderImageScreenName].areas:
        if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
            area.spaces.active.image = bpy.data.images[0]
else:
    bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens[blenderMovieScreenName]
```

Save this as blend_open_image_file.py to match the filename set in the first script.

The list of extensions can easily be extended.

I thought I would keep a copy of this [on github](https://github.com/sambler/BlenderImageViewer) which also has the blend file mentioned above if anyone thinks it can be improved.

Comment: When I open the image he give me a cmd screen that write some line and close again,what am I doing wrong.

Comment: most likely you didn't add the shebang line that I left out - the first line of the script should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Still the same,what should the call script format be?and should I set a path or something before doing anything?

Comment: You probably have to enter the full path to blender in the first calllist item, on osx that would be something like `/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender`

Comment: I am using windows 10,I put blender path instead of "blender",but it is still not working.what should the file format be for the call script?

Answer (score 1):

This is not for OSX ( i don't have access to one ) but the concept is the same as on Windows OS:

- create a folder that contains two files `myscript.bat` and `import_file_script.py`
- assign the file types ( that you want to open with blender ) to be opened by this script ( <kbd>RMB</kbd>->Open_with->choose_default_program   and select the .bat file )
- `myscript.bat` is a batch script ( on OSX shell/apple-script ) and in this file put the following lines :

---

```
@ECHO OFF

SET script=%~dp0import_file_script.py   
SET ext=%~x1                            
SET filename=%~f1                       
SET blender="C:/Program Files/Blender Foundation/Blender/blender.exe"

%blender% --python %script% -- %ext% %filename%
```

---

and in the python script file ( named : import_file_script.py )

```
import bpy
import sys

bpy.ops.wm.console_toggle()

argv = sys.argv
ext = argv[argv.index("--") + 1]  
myfile = argv[argv.index("--") + 2]

if ext in ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg']:
    bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['Image Viewer'] # or just ['UV Editing']
    bpy.ops.image.open(filepath=myfile)
    for area in bpy.data.screens['Image Viewer'].areas : 
        if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR' :
                area.spaces.active.image = bpy.data.images[0]

#you can add elif/switch for multi-extention handling
```

- in your startup blend file you can create a screen layout and call it `Image Viewer` that is simply one UV image area

---

Now when you double click an image it will be handled by the batch script which will call blender that will run the python script responsible for importing ( or just opening ) the file in blender